# backup.sh: line 12: [: Use: integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script named `backup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

alert=90
backup_date=$(date +'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
df -H | awk '{print $5 " " $1}' | while read output;

do
        #echo "Disk Detail: $output"
        usage=$(echo $output | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
        file_sys=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')
        #echo $usage
        if [ "$usage" -ge "$alert" ]        # <--- ERROR HERE!
        then
                echo "CRITICAL FOR $file_sys"
        fi
done
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
backup.sh: line 12: [: Use: integer expression expected
```

(where line 12 is the line that I've marked with `# <--- ERROR HERE!`).

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here. Thanks

Comment: Well, what do `$usage` and `$alert` expand to here? One or both of them isn't an integer expected by `-ge`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this,

```
#!/bin/bash

alert=90
backup_date=$(date +'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
df -H | awk '{print $5 " " $1}' | while read output;

do
        #echo "Disk Detail: $output"
        usage=$(echo $output | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
        file_sys=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')
        #echo $usage
        if [ $usage > $alert ]        # <--- ERROR HERE!
        then
                echo "CRITICAL FOR $file_sys"
        fi
done
```

Comment: This is just wrong. Try `if [ 1 > 2 ] ; then echo "one is greater than two" ; fi`. And look for strange files being created.

Comment: The condition will be true as long as `$usage` expands to a single non-empty string: nothing to do with any lexicographical comparison to `$alert`. `[ "$usage" \> "$alert" ]` *might* be correct, but that's probably just masking an error if you are expecting both operands to be integers.

Answer (score 1):

What about this unique [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) ?

```
max=90
df -h |
    awk -vmax=$max '{
        sub(/%/, "", $5)
        if (NR > 1 && $5 > max) {print "critical " $1 " " $5"% " $NF}
    }'
```

### Output

```
critical /dev/nvme0n1p2 99% /
```